# Unix mail command: Sort by newest first

Tags: email, unix, email-client, gnu

When I use the "mail" command, it prints a list of messages in my inbox in a format like this: `1 Super User         Mon Jun  9 17:13   86/4716  Complete Registration With Stack Exchange` However I've noticed that it does this with the oldest messages first. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Are you wedded to `mail`? there are better command line clients, such as `mailx`, or `pine`.  Pine specifically has better sorting options.

Comment: Not completely. I have just spent a while getting mail set up however, so if there is a way to get this functionality in mail that would be prefered.

Comment: I'd try `pine`, see if that is set up on your system. `pine`, `mutt`, anything but base `mail` - it's pretty clunky.

Comment: In some organizations, adding applications is discouraged, if not forbidden.  `mail` is present on most rpm based systems, at least until rhel 9 switches to s-nail.  It's also available on Ubuntu (probably other deb based systems?).  So the correct answer is the one with more votes, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this as an answer, I'd suggest to use `pine`.

The `mail` command really isn't made for interactive use. It's for bare bones, your system is completely hosed, and you're searching for some email from cron. For anything else, use something newer and designed for day to day use, such as `pine` or `mutt`.

Comment: What is you don't have either pine or mutt on your system?

Comment: how is this the best answer and there is not even a link to install these applications.

Comment: There is a program here which accomplishes the in-place sorting of a mbox format file by the "Date" header.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368003/how-can-i-reorder-an-mbox-file-chronologically/368067#368067

Answer (score 25):

For people still looking for an answer in the base mail application, the best solution I could find is running the `h$` command inside mail to jump to the bottom of the list.

([Source](http://www.johnkerl.org/doc/mail-how-to.html))

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes it should.  And to read the last message, you can just type `.` at the `&` prompt.  Some more helpful tips here:  https://www.johnkerl.org/doc/mail-how-to.html#:~:text=To%20view%20a%20message%2C%20just,to%20n%20(or%20%2B).

Answer (score 0):

There is a program here which accomplishes the in-place sorting of a mbox format file by the "Date" header.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368003/how-can-i-reorder-an-mbox-file-chronologically/368067#368067

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).